# OLED ssd1306, "Set the Oscillator Frequency"?

Tags: i2c, oled

I am working with a [OLED SSD1306](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/SSD1306.pdf) and in the datasheet there is a parameter named "Set the Oscillator Frequency."  It is a four bit value to adjust.

I can't understand the purpose of this.

Can anyone help?

Also I am having artifacts/garbage display randomly, so is it related to speed of this frequency or I2C speed?

Comment: It is used for the pixel clock and determines frame rate

Comment: Yes I got it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update :

Both issues resolved. 
1 - The purpose of those 4 bits are to set  the pixel clock and determines frame rate. 
2 - artifacts/garbage display removed by adding the critical section while writing i2c in OS.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. You have posted this as an answer and you can accept it to indicate that the problem is solved. (The answers count will then turn green on the home page.)